# Observing Array Properties in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I have a property on my class:

```
class Control {
    @bindable households;

    get people() {
        return households
            .map(household => househould.people)
            .reduce((g1, g2) => g1.concat(g2), []);
    }
}
```

Which I use to compute a collection of all `people[]` within all households which is then rendered here:

```
<ul>
    <li repeat.for="person of people">
        ${person.firstName} ${person.lastName} - ${person.phone}
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need the list to update whenever people are added to a household, OR if any of the rendered properties, `firstName`, `lastName`, `phone`, for any element in the computed collection is updated. How can I do this in Aurelia? If I use `@computedFrom()` it will not detect changes to elements of the array, and since the list of people in all households is dynamic, I cannot just create an observer for each element without creating a system for managing when observers should be subscribed / unsubscribed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Dirty Checking

Leave off `@computedFrom()` and you'll achieve the desired behavior.

```
export class App {
  @bindable households;
  get people() {
    const households = this.households || []; // Make sure househoulds is defined.
    return households.reduce((people, household) => people.concat(household.people), []);
  }
}
```

https://gist.run/?id=040775f06aba5e955afd362ee60863aa

Answer (score 1):

Right as I was about to give up on being able to Google for a solution, [Aurelia Signaling came to the rescue](https://www.danyow.net/aurelia-binding-behaviors/#signal). This code ended up working for me:

```
<ul>
    <li repeat.for="person of people">
        <!-- May work without this rendering method,
            this is just closer to what my actual code is doing. -->
        ${renderPersonInfo(person) & signal: 'example-signal'}
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the class:

```
import {BindingSignaler} from 'aurelia-templating-resources';

@inject(BindingSignaler)
class Control {
    @bindable households;

    constructor(bindingSignaler) {
        this.bindingSignaler = bindingSignaler;
        //Obviously, you can have this trigger off any event
        setInterval(() => this.bindingSignaler.signal('example-signal'), 1000);
    }

    get people() {
        return households
            .map(household => househould.people)
            .reduce((g1, g2) => g1.concat(g2), []);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you just use a getter, without `computedFrom`, and without signals - you should get the same effect - because aurelia will default to the `dirty` strategy of recomputing the getter 5 times a second. ALSO: dont forget to dispose your interval on detached.

Comment: dirty-check is not a sin :-) It's the only trick that angular v1 needed.

Comment: Hmm, I've tested with this and it didn't work for me. Switched to a simple method and behavior is quite different.

Answer (score 0):

You must avoid `dirty-checking` as far as possible, signals are the perfect option for your scenario. Just bear in mind that if you want to use `computedFrom` on an array you can do so by watching its `length` property for instance rather than  `dirtyChecking`, sth like the following `@computedFrom("myArray.length")`